# moving slider i want the center one in the viewport be bigger by CSS or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a moving slider. I want the center img elements when being in the center of the viewport and come back to the old size and the next element to come bigger when being in the center of the viewport and come back to the old size and so on can I have help with CSS or JavaScript and thanks, I attached my html code and the CSS.

```css
.slider {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slider ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: max-content;
  animation: runSlider 20s linear infinite; 
}

.slider img {
  width: 40vw;
  height: 25vw;
  border-radius: 5vw;
}

.slider li {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: start;
  align-items: center;
  margin-right: 5vw;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  height: 40vw;
}

.center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 10%;
  transform: translate(0%, -50%);
  font-size: 4vw;
  text-align: end;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px black;
}

@keyframes runSlider {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(calc(-45vw * 4));
  }
}
```

```html
</head>
<body>
<section class="slider">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <img src="https://placehold.co/600x400" alt="" class="elementSlide">
          <div class="center">Hi<br>Hello World</div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="https://placehold.co/600x400" alt="" class="elementSlide">
          <div class="center">Hi<br>Hello World</div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="https://placehold.co/600x400" alt="" class="elementSlide">
          <div class="center">Hi<br>Hello World</div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="https://placehold.co/600x400" alt="" class="elementSlide">
          <div class="center">Hi<br>Hello World</div>
        </li>

        <li>
          <img src="https://placehold.co/600x400" alt="" class="elementSlide">
          <div class="center">Hi<br>Hello World</div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="https://placehold.co/600x400" alt="" class="elementSlide">
          <div class="center">Hi<br>Hello World</div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="https://placehold.co/600x400" alt="" class="elementSlide">
          <div class="center">Hi<br>Hello World</div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="https://placehold.co/600x400" alt="" class="elementSlide">
          <div class="center">Hi<br>Hello World</div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </section>
</body>
```

Comment: Have you looked into 3D carousels, or do you want to stay 2d?

Comment: I suggest you to use OWL Carousel like:
https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/ and some reference  https://codepen.io/onigetoc/pen/qBEKXEo =